# Calculating frequency for each column and calculating the frequency for the whole matrix

Tags: r, tidyverse, frequency

My matrix looks like the following table

```
v1  v2  v3
M   Z   P
Z   Z   P
P   Z   M
Z   P   Z
```

I wan to calculate the frequency for each column and then calculate the frequency for the whole data. The desired outcome is:

```
Factor  V1  V2  V3  Freq  Percentage
M       1   0   1   2     16.66666667
P       1   1   2   4     33.33333333
Z       2   3   1   6     50
```

I tried `sapply(df, table)`, but it did not work. Any help would be great, especially using `tidyverse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way with `table` and `addmargins`

```
out <- addmargins(table(unlist(df1), c(col(df1))), 2)
cbind(out, Percentage = 100 *out[,4]/sum(out[, 4]))
#  1 2 3 Sum Percentage
#M 1 0 1   2  16.66667
#P 1 1 2   4  33.33333
#Z 2 3 1   6  50.00000
```

---

Or in a more compact way

```
library(qdapTools)
transform(as.data.frame(addmargins(t(mtabulate(df1)), 2)),
                 Percentage = 100 * Sum/sum(Sum))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, Factor) %>%
    dplyr::count(key, Factor) %>% 
    spread(key, n, fill = 0) %>% 
    mutate(Freq = rowSums(.[-1]), 
           Percentage = 100 * Freq/sum(Freq))
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  Factor    v1    v2    v3  Freq Percentage
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 M          1     0     1     2       16.7
#2 P          1     1     2     4       33.3
#3 Z          2     3     1     6       50
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("M", "Z", "P", "Z"), v2 = c("Z", "Z", "Z", 
 "P"), v3 = c("P", "P", "M", "Z")), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: @USER2313456  That is easy `gather(df1, key, Factor) %>% mutate(key = factor(key, levels = unique(key))) %>% spread`

Comment: @USER2313456 I meant to use `spread(key, n, fill = 0)` after the previous comment

Comment: @USER2313456  Are you saying that all the 3 solutions Ii posted are coming as error

Comment: @USER2313456 `gather(df1, key, Factor) %>% mutate(key = factor(key, levels = unique(key))) %>% dplyr::count(key, Factor)  %>% spread(key, n, fill = 0) %>% mutate(Freq = rowSums(.[-1]), Percentage = 100 * Freq/sum(Freq))` works for me

Comment: I think earlier, I forgot the `count` step in between